# Jquery DataTables - Removes last row in table with complex header when scroll Y enabled

Tags: scroll, datatable, datatables, header

I'm using Jquery DataTables 1.10.18. I'm converting an existing HTML table to Datatable. My table has complex header. For complex header to work in Jquery DataTables, I have added another empty row in my table header and made that to be a hidden row with bootstrap class of "d-none".

Now when I initialize my datatable, the last row is always removed by Jquery Datatable. This happens only If number of rows is greater than 10.

I have inserted my code snippet in this post. Kindly Assist.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="tableContainer" class="w-100 mw-100 overflow-x-hidden">
        <table id="test" class="table table-bordered table-sm mt-0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="1" style="width:400px;">
                        <h2 class="h6 text-purple text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Description</h2>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="4" class="py-0">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center text-dark">
                            <div class="w-30">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="abs">
                                    <label class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal" for="abs">chkbox</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-30">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm">Test</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w-40">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-normal" style="padding-top:11px;"
                                        for="abs2">Test :</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 py-1">
                                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="abs2"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-flex flex-row align-content-center">
                            <span class="text-danger d-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="d-none">
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr data-row-id="0">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        1 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[0]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="0Yes" name="[0]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="0Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="0No" name="[0]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="0No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="0Admin" name="[0]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="0Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="0NotAdmin" name="[0]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="0NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="1">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        2 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[1]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="1Yes" name="[1]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="1Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="1No" name="[1]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="1No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="1Admin" name="[1]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="1Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="1NotAdmin" name="[1]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="1NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="2">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        3 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[2]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="2Yes" name="[2]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="2Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="2No" name="[2]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="2No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="2Admin" name="[2]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="2Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="2NotAdmin" name="[2]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="2NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="3">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        4 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[3]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="3Yes" name="[3]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="3Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="3No" name="[3]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="3No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="3Admin" name="[3]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="3Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="3NotAdmin" name="[3]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="3NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="4">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        5 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[4]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="4Yes" name="[4]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="4Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="4No" name="[4]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="4No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="4Admin" name="[4]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="4Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="4NotAdmin" name="[4]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="4NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="5">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        6 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[5]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="5Yes" name="[5]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="5Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="5No" name="[5]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="5No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="5Admin" name="[5]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="5Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="5NotAdmin" name="[5]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="5NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="6">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        7 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[6]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="6Yes" name="[6]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="6Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="6No" name="[6]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="6No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="6Admin" name="[6]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="6Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="6NotAdmin" name="[6]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="6NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="7">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        8 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[7]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="7Yes" name="[7]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="7Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="7No" name="[7]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="7No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="7Admin" name="[7]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="7Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="7NotAdmin" name="[7]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="7NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="8">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        9 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[8]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="8Yes" name="[8]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="8Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="8No" name="[8]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="8No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="8Admin" name="[8]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="8Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="8NotAdmin" name="[8]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="8NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="9">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        10 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[9]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="9Yes" name="[9]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="9Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="9No" name="[9]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="9No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="9Admin" name="[9]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="9Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="9NotAdmin" name="[9]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="9NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-row-id="10">
                    <td style="width: 400px; white-space: normal" class="align-middle">
                        11 <br />
                        <span class="text-danger d-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Grid[10]"
                            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="10Yes" name="[10]" class="custom-control-input" value="Yes" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="10Yes">Yes</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="10No" name="[10]" class="custom-control-input" value="No" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="10No">No</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="10Admin" name="[10]" class="custom-control-input" value="Admin"
                                checked="checked" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="10Admin">Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="bg-info-lighter py-0 align-middle">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input type="radio" id="10NotAdmin" name="[10]" class="custom-control-input"
                                value="NotAdmin" />
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="DataAbstractor10NotAdmin">Not Admin</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            if ($('#test').length !== 0) {
                var test = $('#test').DataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    scrollY: 200,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    processing: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    deferRender: true,
                    language: {
                        processing: "Loading...",
                        zeroRecords: "No matching records found"
                    },
                    ordering: false,
                    dom: '<tr>'
                });

            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess issue is with `pageLength`, default value in 10

Refer [Doc](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength)

You can add `pageLength` in dataTable initialization like this

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

or

for `DataTables` version `1.10.5` and newer you can specify in HTML itself like this

```
<table data-page-length='25'>
     ...
</table>
```

Comment: You save my day. Many thanks @MyTwoCents. Thanks for helping with pagination thought. Your answer works like a charm. But I prefer to keep that logic with my scripts. So I added `paging: false` in my DataTable Initialization and that fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. :)